# How to retrieve data from data_type RAW in Oracle with Groovy?

Tags: sql, oracle, groovy

I have a table in oracle db with data type RAW.

I would like export into an xml file but when I retrieve the data from the RAW column I get a [@4r5... instead of the value in db (123454678...)

How can I write this value in xml (the goal is to export in another db)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what code you're using to access the column, but it looks like you are getting back a `byte[]`

You should be able to print the actual bytes in groovy using:

```
println obj.toList().join(',')
```

But if you were expecting a string or something, you'll need to know how it was converted to bytes in the first place...

If you want the byte array converted to an array of integers, you can just do:

```
List byteList =  a.toList()
```

(or if you want your bytes to be treated as unsigned, you can do)

```
List byteList =  a.collect { it & 0xff }
```

It depends what you intend to do with the array though...  It is probably best left as an array...

Comment: just a sql.eachRow('select myRawColumn from mytable'){}
Thanks a lot. I'll try it tomorrow

Comment: I have this : 
sql.eachRow(queryUsers){ u -> 
  println u.mycolumn.join(',')
}
But it is not working. I receive this error : B.join() is applicable for String. Value is [,]

Any other idea ?

Comment: I would like copy in XML to copy mu table to another. The girls is the password of the user. I migratre mu database to à new one and it should from oracle to MySQL. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're going to have to come up with some way of encoding your byte array in xml. Converting to a string probably won't cut it, as you can end up with characters that aren't allowed in xml. You probably want to use `obj.encodeBase64()` which is documented [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/primitive-types/byte%5B%5D.html#encodeBase64())

Answer (score 0):

Did you try PL/SQL?

```
declare
  a mytable.rawcol%TYPE;
begin
  select rawcol into a from mytable;
  -- now do something with "a"
end;
```